# Bash: read inside while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

Let me introduce my loop to you all:

```
NUM_LINE=0
while read line; do
  let NUM_LINE+=1
  if [ $NUM_LINE -lt 41 ]; then
    echo -e "\t$BLANC|$ORIGINAL $line $BLANC|"
  else 
    echo -e "\n\t$BLANC## "$GRIS"Llista de Nodes sel·leccionats    $BLANC############$ORIGINAL\n"
    read AUX
    NUM_LINE=0  
  fi
done <$NODES
```

So that:

---

$BLANC is `\033[1;37m`
$GRIS same
$ORIGINAL as well
$NODES is the absolute path of a file containg a lot of lines like: 
`| 23127           myserver    98.194.263.29 |`

The Problem:

---

The `echo` inside the `else` statement it's properly triggered.
But it doesn't happen the same with the `read` statement

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that the loop doesn't function properly is because read is reading from stdin in both cases. You need to open an alternate file descriptor to your file and read from the file descriptor.

```
exec 3<$NODES
NUM_LINE=0
while read -u 3 -r line; do
  (( NUM_LINE++ ))
  if (( NUM_LINE < 41 )); then
    echo -e "\t$BLANC|$ORIGINAL $line $BLANC|"
  else 
    echo -e "\n\t$BLANC## "$GRIS"Llista de Nodes sel·leccionats    $BLANC############$ORIGINAL\n"
    read AUX
    NUM_LINE=0  
  fi
done
```

Comment: Instead of using `exec 3<$NODES` before the loop, you could also use `done 3<$NODES` at the end of the loop.  IMHO this is slightly cleaner, as it doesn't leave a stale connection to the $NODE file after the loop has ended.